# Which is the best way to fetch 1-M relationship data?

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework and I have a Post that has many comments, I need to get a list of posts, and each post should hold the latest 5 comments with it.

1. First Option: Is to make a join between posts and comments table and in the PHP code I should normalize the posts list to remove the duplicates and put the commets inside each related post.
2. Second Option: Is to load the posts list, then in PHP code iterate over these posts list and load the comments for each post using a separate sql hit.

Which one has the best performance and is there any better way to do it?

Comment: This sounds like the old Top N per Group problem. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) and others linked from it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never have incremental hits on your database because of the data. Therefore, the first option would be the wisest one. If you do a join and then filter away the stuff you do not need, your program will be a lot faster than if you do one more database lookup for each row the previous query returned.

For more information, have a look on lazy and eager loading here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/34412-eager-loading-vs-lazy-loading/

Comment: yes, I agree with this answer, loading all data in one query is much better than second option.

Comment: thanks for pointing me into the right direction, also I think this article will be helpful to apply the above concept using Yii framework http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/428/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation/